# add layer over mapView from TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, android-mapview

I know it's possible because in cocos2d you can add layers but I am a little lost. I want to add a layer over a mapView. Normally I would just call addSubView: but the problem is that it needs to be called from a tab bar. When I call a view from the tab Bar it covers the whole mapView. All I really want it to do is add a toolbar that I created(play button, pause button, stop button) and use CGRectMake to determine where I want it to go. The best way I can think of explaining this functionality is to think of an overlay. It just adds a layer on the map. Maybe someone could shed some light on the best approach to do this. Thank you.

//app delegate example. Leaving out initialization of view1,view2,view3

```
self.tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2,view3, nil];
[self.window addSubview:tabBar.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are looking to add views on top of an existing uiview (such as MapView) then a TabBar is definitely not the right choice. A TabBar is designed to replace the entire view. You could make different view controllers that have a map view and different layers on top. If you want to always use the same MapView, a UIToolbar is your best bet. Just have the buttons on it add/remove views.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html